# Unknown member 'Header' on element 'ComboBox'

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

The below line of code is throwing such an error.

```
<ComboBox Header="Please Select Type" ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"/>
```

I didn't find more information regarding `ComboBox`'s [`Header`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.header%28v=win.10%29.aspx) property. Does any one know what's the use of it?

Comment: Have you tried putting the header in a child element as it shows in the documentation you linked?

Comment: a `ComboBox` obviously does not have any property `Header`.

Comment: @jbabey yes I tried, not working.

Comment: @KingKing then why that MSDN documentation does exist?

Answer (score 0):

`Header` property is available for Windows 8.1/VS2013 only, so it will throw error if any one tries to use in Windows 8/VS2012

Answer (score 0):

The property is there and works fine for me. It's also there for input controls like TextBox or PasswordBox. Perhaps you are trying it out in a Windows 8.0 project.

Oh and it provides a header you can associate with your control, so it shows up in the recommended, localization-safe position (above the control) and saves you from defining a TextBlock label for each input control. Possibly to make it easier to create forms-like UIs (disclaimer - I don't really know).